# hadoop test examples to validate the installation

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have successfully configured `Hadoop 2.4` on my Ubuntu `14.04` using this tutorial.

http://dogdogfish.com/2014/04/26/installing-hadoop-2-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Now after completing installtion how can I perform test on it?

How and where can I get the test data or jar files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some example jars in your hadoop installation directory.

Simplest thing you can do is run the teragen example(or wordcount).
It is the first step in perform terasort.

Steps:

1. Go to the hadoop installation directory.
2. Run "hadoop jar hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u0.jar" to see all the jars you can run.
3. Go to home/[user] directory and create a file "example.txt" with the following data 
   "This is a file to test Hadoop Installation example
   For the sake of the experiment, consider it to be 1TB"
4. While you are in that directory, run "hadoop dfs -put examples.txt /" this uploads the file onto your HDFS
5. Run "hadoop dfs -ls /" to check it is on there
6. Go to your Hadoop installation directory and run "hadoop jar hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u0.jar teragen 1000 /user/teragendata" - 1000 is the size data is to be broken into and the other param is the output directory.
7. On successful execution, you will see something like the text at the bottom.
8. Now to see how your MR job was run, in your browser open JobTracker and see the completed jobs. "localhost50030/jobtracker.jsp"

---

cloudera@cloudera-vm:/usr/lib/hadoop$ hadoop jar hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u0.jar teragen 600 /user/teragendata

Generating 600 using 2 maps with step of 300

14/07/24 09:02:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201407230030_0008

14/07/24 09:02:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%

14/07/24 09:02:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201407230030_0008

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 13

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=22008

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=2

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=164

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=105150

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=60000

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=600

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=600

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=600

14/07/24 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=164